# Video on Android didn´t work

Tags: javascript, android, sencha-touch

i have do a app with the framework Sencha Touch with the function `xtype:Video`.

all works fine on the Apple Series..
but on android it open the player and the screen is black no Video play.
i have try many formats... mp4,webm etc....

nothink works.

I use also the Programm Any Video Converter Pro and Android converter. no chance...

anyone knows whats the problem ist? wrong format?
please help me guys.

```
vpanel = new Ext.Panel({
                fullscreen: true,
                id:'vvideo',
                dock:'center',
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype    : 'video',
                        width    : '100%',
                        height   : '100%',
                        url      : 'http://xxxxx,
                        posterUrl: 'xxx.jpg'
                    }
                ],
            });
```

Comment: The url is missing an apostrophe at the end. Is that a typo?

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 Media elements are not fully supported on Android until version 2.3. Version 2.2 has SOME support, but you should pretty much just ignore it because its pitiful. I assume that you are testing on an Android device that isn't running at least 2.3.

Comment: i test it on Android 4.0. but it dont work.
a mate tell me now, that is a unfixed bug in android.

Comment: so letz wait for 4.X. hope they fix it fast ;)